# recursive function using gmail api returning same result

Tags: node.js, recursion, output, gmail-api

Following is a recursive function which logs data fetched from a gmail api.

```
function listAllMessages(auth, nextPageToken = ''){
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    let options = {
        userId: 'me',
        nextPageToken: nextPageToken,
    }
    gmail.users.messages.list(options, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log("ListAllMessages returned an error" + err);
//        console.log(res.data);
        if(res.data.nextPageToken){
            console.log(res.data.nextPageToken);
            listAllMessages(auth, res.data.nextPageToken);
        }
    })
}
```

Rather than printing the next page tokens, the function is printing the same page token consecutively. The first call must go without any page token, while the consecutive calls take the token given in the response of the previous call and print the token of the next page.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Example of required output:
token1
token2
token3
.
.
.
tokenN

Example of current output:
token1
token1
token1
token1
.
.
.
.

Comment: In the line `console.log(res.data.nextPageToken)` do you actually get a different token each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [gmail.users.messages.list api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#javascript) you should make the request with `pageToken` but instead you use `nextPageToken`.

Change your code to this

```js
function listAllMessages(auth, nextPageToken = ''){
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    let options = {
        userId: 'me',
        pageToken: nextPageToken,
    }
    gmail.users.messages.list(options, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log("ListAllMessages returned an error" + err);
        if(res.data.nextPageToken){
            console.log(res.data.nextPageToken);
            listAllMessages(auth, res.data.nextPageToken);
        }
    })
}
```